# PNG Alpha transparency in email

Tags: email, png, email-client

Is there support for PNG alpha transparency for popular email clients?

Here are the list of major e-mail clients i'm planning to support:

Web based*

- Gmail
- Hotmail
- Yahoo

Software based

- Outlook 2007/2010
- Windows Mail
- Mac OSX Mail
- Thunderbird

Mobile based

- iOS Device Mail
- Android Device Mail

**This is browser-based, so no need to worry about this*

From the research i've done, it seems all (mobile-based isn't listed, but i checked my phones) support PNG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Messages_features).  But, I'm unsure as to whether or not they support transparency.    Anyone have any good insight into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out.  I think that most will support PNG.  I think that outlook 2003 used to have that problem because it was using the IE rendering engine.  Nowadays, PNG is fairly acceptable. BUT, be a little careful with alpha transparencies.

But anyway, litmus has been the best thing i've used thus far.  So, I suggest to use that if you are very serious about testing on all available platforms